# Exactness of a 1-form

Tags: differential-forms

This may be a trivial question. If so, apologies in advance.

Let a $1$-form $\omega$ be given. Suppose that for any line segments $C_1=[i,j]$, $C_2=[j,k]$, $C_3=[i,k]$, we have that 
$\int_{C_1} \omega + \int_{C_2} \omega = \int_{C_3} \omega$.

My question is whether this implies that $\omega$ is exact. If this were true for any curves $C_1,C_2,C_3$, I believe the answer would be affirmative. I want to make sure that restricting attention to finitely (or countably) many line segments is without loss of generality.

Comment: What is the domain of your 1-form? If it's the plane, or the punctured plane, you're fine. If it's the plane minus , say, a fattened letter "E" shape, then it requires a bit more proof. If it's the plane minus something  like a deformed topologist's-sine-curve, or other such weirdness, I wouldn't be willing to commit. :)

Comment: Thanks @JohnHughes. It is set of $M\times N$ matrices whose entries are nonnegative and add up to one.

Comment: It should be fine using just horizontal and vertical line segments (and the diagonals connecting endpoints, of course). Think about the usual proof of constructing a potential function given an $\omega$ whose line integrals are path-independent. We just need to know that varying $x$ and then $y$ gives the same result as first varying $y$ and then $x$.

Comment: Ah...so it's on a convex subset of $\Bbb R^{N+M}$ of codimension 1. In that case, this condition should be sufficient...but it may be far easier to show that the form is exact by computing its exterior derivative and getting 0; that'll show it's closed, hence exact (because the space is contractible).